# How can I login to Amazon after I lost my phone?

Tags: amazon

I could not login to my Amazon.com account as I already lost my old phone number. But it forces me to login using the one-time password that is sent via SMS.

[image]

I could not access to the SMS so I clicked the Amazon Customer Service link, but it only guides me to the following page.

[image]

I manually went to the Help link on the bottom of the website, but it forces me to login which I could not.

How can I contact the Customer Service? (I don't live in the USA and could not call them...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that by changing the language to either Chinese or Korean, the website shows the contact page, letting you contact the support team. I use English to contact them but it was no problem.

After I explained the problem to them, they unlocked the security and let me log it with the original email and password.